# Uninstall one of few Mathematica versions on Linux

Tags: installation, version-12.1

I currently have *Mathematica* 11.3 and 12.0 installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I just downloaded *Mathematica* 12.1.1 and would like to remove 12.0 and install 12.1.1, while still keeping 11.3.

The instructions on the [Wolfram page](https://support.wolfram.com/12473?src=mathematica) do not mention anything about handling multiple versions. I know that I can run the installer script of 12.1.1 and it will ask me whether to overwrite old files or not. In that way I can easily have all three versions installed at the same time. But I do not want 12.0.

I know that '/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/' contains folders for every version, but is it enough to just delete the 12.0 folder? What about all the other locations listed on the [Wolfram page](https://support.wolfram.com/12473?src=mathematica)?

Comment: The last three folders (starting from ~) are for user files. The first one contains the Mathematica components and the second one is for shared components of all Mathematica versions. You can remove the first one.

Comment: @Rom38 Shall I first install Mathematica 12.1.1 and then remove the components of 12.0 or the other way around. Do they share the same configuration files?

Comment: kill the old version of MMa first, then install the new one. Of course, it will set up the new version into separate folder but..